# In Angular, how to handle the case where a setter depends on an input?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two `@Input` props, and I want to monitor one of them, and do something everytime it changes.

However, this "do something" is dependent on another `@Input`.

For example

```
  // This is the 1st input prop, which is monitored using a setter
  private _inputOne: string;

  @Input() set inputOne(value: string) {
    this._inputOne= value;

    // Whether the setter needs to do something depends on another input called "inputTwo"
    if (this.inputTwo) {
        ... do something
    }
  }

  get _inputOne(): string {
    return this._inputOne;
  }

  // This is the 2nd input prop.
  @Input() inputTwo: boolean;
```

The problem is that, the setter `set inputOne(value: string)` seems to have no access to the other input `inputTwo`. From its POV, `inputTwo` is always `undefined`, but it really needs its actual value.

I am wondering how to solve this issue...

Maybe I can pass in **both of them** from the parent component everytime only `inputOne` is changed, then use the `ngOnChanges` hook, because it has access to both of them, but is there a more elegant solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `inputTwo` isn't probably set yet when the setter fires. What is wrong with `ngOnChanges` you don't have to modify anything in parent component to use it.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski But I think I do need to modify the parent component. Because by its nature it only alters `inputOne`, but to make `inputTwo` appear in `ngOnChanges`, it has to alter `inputTwo` too, is that right? Because `ngOnChanges` only has values that have changes, but not unchanged ones.

Comment: You can access `this` in `ngOnChanges` as usuall so all values are there

Comment: `inputTwo` is undefined on the first time it `inputOne` change or everytime?

Comment: @EliPorush Only the first time I think.

Comment: so try to move `inputTwo` above `inputOne` in the component order

Comment: @EliPorush I just tried but didn't work

Comment: @EliPorush Oh, `inputTwo` must be passed in before `inputOne` in the parent component! I tried and this way it worked! But it is not the best practice I think, for forcing a certain order for the props...

Comment: Note that `doSomething` will be called tons of times. Also, I use `BehaviorSubject`s for this type of stuff. The `@Input` sets the corresponding `BehaviorSubject`, use `combineLatest` to project a new value from both bs...

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't rely on the order those Inputs are set. You could wait for a Promise that is resolved in the ngOnInit hook. ngOnInit is called after the Inputs are set.

```js
@Component(/* ... */)
class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    private _inputOne: string;

    @Input()
    public set inputOne(value: string) {
        this._inputOne = value;
        this.onInitCalled.then(() => {
            if (this.inputTwo) {
                // do something
            }
        });
    }
    public get inputOne(): string { return this._inputOne; }
    @Input() public inputTwo: boolean;

    private onInit = new Subject<void>();
    private onInitCalled = firstValueFrom(this.onInit);
    ngOnInit() {
        this.onInit.next();
        this.onInit.complete();
    }
}
```

Or you could just replace your "do something" with a function call, skip it if inputTwo is undefined and call the function from your ngOnInit hook.